# How to test access token for HTTP callouts?

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock

I have an access token for my HTTP callouts. How can I test it if I wanna use Static Resource? But I can also use the HttpCalloutMock Interface. it doesn't matter

My access token is in custom object. I just call fields in the method.

```
public static String accessToken(){
//Error is here:
    Token__c tok = [SELECT ConsumerKey__c, ClientSecret__c, Username__c, Password__c, SecurityToken__c
                            FROM Token__c 
                            WHERE Name = 'OurToken'];  
    String consumerKey = tok.ConsumerKey__c;
    String consumerSecret = tok.ClientSecret__c;
    String username = tok.Username__c;
    String password = tok.Password__c + tok.SecurityToken__c;
    String request = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + consumerKey +'&client_secret=' + consumerSecret +
                     '&username=' + username + '&password='+password;
    return request;
}
```

I have my test, but it's write me an Error:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

```
@isTest
static void testCallout() {
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    String requestBody = Callout.accessToken();  //error is here
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(requestBody);
    ourRequest.setMethod('POST');
    ourRequest.setEndpoint(System.Label.URL + '/services/oauth2/token');
    HttpResponse response2 = ourHttp.send(ourRequest);
}
```

Comment: provide code, that throws exception. You didn't show us `Callout.accessTokenBody` method

Comment: Sorry. It's a accessToken() method.

Comment: can you highlight a line in `accessToken`, where exception is thrown  ?

Comment: Done. To bad that I can't answer here in russian :)

Answer (score 2):

in tests methods without `seeAllData = true` property of annotation `@isTest` **only data created in test method and in methods annotated with @testSetup is visible**. this is a copcept of [test data isolation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)

you have to create tour `Token__c` record before invoking `Callout.accessTokenBody();` in test.

```
@isTest
static void testCallout() {
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
    insert new Token__c(
        Name = 'OurToken',
        .....
        );
    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    String requestBody = Callout.accessToken();  //error is here
    HttpRequest ourRequest = new HttpRequest();
    ourRequest.setBody(requestBody);
    ourRequest.setMethod('POST');
    ourRequest.setEndpoint(System.Label.URL + '/services/oauth2/token');
    HttpResponse response2 = ourHttp.send(ourRequest);
}
```

Comment: Coverage is still null. It's our web token to make integration between 2 orgs. I don't think I can make it custom. Now I have:

insert new Token__c(Name = 'OurToken',
                               ConsumerKey__c = '3MVG9I1kFE5Iul2DdHpJB2OydGLbG***************************************,
                               ClientSecret__c = '473837323*********',
                               Username__c = 'email@email.com',
                               SecurityToken__c = '4qVSDcdY****************',
                               Password__c = 'mypassword');

Comment: Error is the same: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject